# Year full of un-linked commits. Possible to retain?

Tags: git, github, commit

As it seems my git config had changed itself somehow so all the commits were in my real name but not linked to my github account. There is well over 1500 commits that I have "lost" as in stats on the project and on my page contributions.

I have managed to link my account with the correct email now, but the other commits have our local domain's email eg: "user@server.local".

Is it possible to link all these commits to my real account?

Comment: Just to clarify: is it the case that the only thing preventing these commits from being linked is that the email address in the commit data doesn't match the one from your Github profile? So all you want to do is change the email address on these commits?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, I dont think there is a possible way to register "solve@server.local", or is there?

Comment: Original commit author is baked into the commit, I believe you'd have to completely rewrite your history to get it fixed. It may be feasible if it is a private repo, but for public repo this would break it for everyone.

Comment: No, I don't think you can sign up for Github with an email address for a local domain like that. But it is possible to rewrite the commit history. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Frax It is indeed a private repo. However, I cannot go ham on the repo as I'm just one of many that works on the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github gives [a procedure for changing the author information (including email) of past commits](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/). Basically, you enter the information in the appropriate place in this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="user@server.local"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

and run it. The various options are described in the man page brought up by `git help filter-branch`, if you're curious; in brief, `--env-filter` tells git that you will be modifying the environment variables associated with a commit, `--tag-name-filter cat` tells it not to change the content of tags, and `--branches` and `--tags` tell git to apply the changes to commits which are reachable from all branches and tags in your repository. After that completes, you can check the history and force-push it:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

Running that command will effectively remove and replace the entire history of your repository on Github. If people have forked or cloned it, this will cause problems for them, so in that case you might actually want to start a new repository with the history you have after running the command, and deprecate the old one.

Comment: Not sure if it will work for OP, but it's a nice answer anyway. However, please bold the sentence "Running that command will effectively remove and replace the entire history of your repository on Github", it's important!

Comment: Well put together answer! Didn't think this would have such a impact on the structures, but I will give it a try in the morning if the team agrees on such a bold move

Comment: @Frax I agree that's important, but I made an intentional decision not to put it in bold - that's not the type of emphasis I want. In general, I would rather trust people to actually read the answer. (But I could see italicizing it, perhaps.)

Comment: I suppose I will accept this answer as this is more or less the only logical solution to problems regarding un-registerable emails. I think this will help people in the future aswell. However, I do see your point  but @Frax has a better one; there is a lot of people skimming through accepted answers.

Comment: Also, that script will reset the time stamp of the commit...also not good if you are concerned about the pretty graphs on GitHub, GitLab, and BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you setup a repo on github, establish this as a new remote for project and then push your project, all of the commit history will carry to the remote.

Comment: That may mark the commits as uploaded by OP, but not as commited by OP.